# How do I sort filenames in a folder containing sub-folders recursively using Python

Tags: python-3.x, databricks

I am new to Python and using Databricks. I have a folder with multiple sub-folders containing files with filenames that look like:

```
Input (A_B)
=====
1_1.json.gz
1_22.json.gz
7_33.json.gz
1_4.json.gz
2_1.json.gz
2_22.json.gz
9_33.json.gz
2_4.json.gz
```

How can I extract both integers from the file name and use them to sort in this fashion:

```
Output (Order by B Asc, A Desc)
======
2_1.json.gz
1_1.json.gz
2_4.json.gz
1_4.json.gz
2_22.json.gz
1_22.json.gz
9_33.json.gz
7_33.json.gz
```

I tried the following code but was unable to get the expected output:

```
import os
from os import path
path = '/dbfs/FileStore/MainFolder'
arrayfiles = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
   for file in files:
      if file.endswith('.json.gz'):
         print(file)
         arrayfiles.append(file)
print(arrayfiles)
arrayfiles.sort()
print(arrayfiles)
```

I have a similar question again if you can help me in this as well it would be great.So in the above input lets treat integer before underscore as 'A' and after underscore as 'B' and the output which you helped me is sort by(B Asc,A Desc).How canI sort on B,A or B Desc and A Ascn? Can I use this same bubble sort alg?? –
What if in place of integers if I have string ..how I can sort then??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this bubble sort algorithm :

```
def custom_bubble_sort(arr):
    def swap(i, j):
        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

    def getFirstNum(st):
        return int(st.split(".")[0].split("_")[0])

    def getSecondNum(st):
        return int(st.split(".")[0].split("_")[1])

    n = len(arr)
    swapped = True

    x = -1
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        x = x + 1
        for i in range(1, n-x):


            if getSecondNum(arr[i - 1]) > getSecondNum(arr[i]):
                swap(i - 1, i)
                swapped = True
            elif getSecondNum(arr[i - 1]) == getSecondNum(arr[i]):
                if getFirstNum(arr[i - 1]) < getFirstNum(arr[i]):
                    swap(i - 1, i)
                    swapped = True

    return arr



a = ['1_1.json.gz',
    '1_22.json.gz',
    '7_33.json.gz',
    '1_4.json.gz',
    '2_1.json.gz',
    '2_22.json.gz',
    '9_33.json.gz',
    '2_4.json.gz']

print(custom_bubble_sort(a))
```

Comment: I have a similar question again if you can help me in this as well it would be great.So in the above input lets treat integer before underscore as 'A' and after underscore as 'B' and the output which you helped me is sort by(B Asc,A Desc).How canI sort on B,A or B Desc and A Ascn? Can I use this same bubble sort alg??

Comment: Yes, simply replace ‘>’ with ‘<‘ in the first if statement and ‘<‘ with ‘>’ in the other comparaison. Or simply reverse the first list by calling yourList.reverse()